# Have Nginx hold requests while app is reloading

Tags: nginx

I have an nginx reverse proxy server set up to forward requests to an app running on port 5000 via `proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;`.

This works, however when I restart the app, for about 10 sec any requests immediately return `502 Bad Gateway`, until the app reloads again.

Is there any way to set up Nginx to hold those requests while the app is down, retrying every so often?  I've tried

```
upstream backend {                         
  server localhost:5000 fail_timeout=20s; 
  server localhost:5000 backup;          
}
...
    proxy_pass http://backend;
```

but that doesn't seem to have an effect.

Comment: This was discussed on their mailing-list: https://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,177,177 They don't seem to believe in the use case either.

Comment: I finally found a working solution at https://serverfault.com/a/871806/187237 using the Lua module

Comment: Does this answer your question? [nginx proxy retry while backend is restarting](https://serverfault.com/questions/259665/nginx-proxy-retry-while-backend-is-restarting)

Comment: Hmm, that was three companies ago. I can't remember how we eventually solved it. It was a private API so I think we ended up just retrying on the client.

Answer (score 1):

You have some options :

- Search into your upstream doc to find a proper reload signal/api instead of a stop & start sequence.
- If your pages can be cached, define a proxy cache and serve stale pages until the app goes up again.
- Scale the backend to 2 instances and restart one at a time, then tune `proxy_next_upstream` if necessary.